# Dealing with refs in function component without forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook, react-forwardref

I'm having a situation with refs and simply looking for a workaround.

https://github.com/styleguidist/react-docgen-typescript/issues/314

Using a utility method that is essentially React.forwardRef under the hood is breaking the automatic type documentation in my Storybook.

I don't mind temporarily exporting 2 components:

1. One without forwardRef for Storybook
2. One with forwardRefWithAs for application usage

However, this obviously doesn't just... "work" because of refs not passing implicitly in normal functions.

**Is something like this viable? Are there any gotchas with it?**

```
// i'll use a generic
const useForwardedRef = (ref: React.Ref<any>) =>{
  const innerRef = useRef<any>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref) return;
    if (typeof ref === 'function') {
      ref(innerRef.current);
    } else {
      ref.current = innerRef.current;
    }
  });
 
  return innerRef;
}
```

**I could also just do:**

```
export const ButtonWithoutForwardRefWithAs = forwardRef((props: ButtonProps, ref: React.Ref<any>) => <JSX {...props} ref={ref} />

const Button = forwardRefWithAs<NonSemanticButtonProps, 'button'>((props: ButtonProps, ref) => (
  <ButtonWithoutForwardRefWithAs {...props} ref={ref} />
));
```

## What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

This ended up having nothing to do with the utility method. Instead, it had to do with how I was exporting things.

Previously:

```
const Button = forwardRefWithAs<NonSemanticButtonProps, 'button'>((props: ButtonProps, ref) => (
  <ButtonWithoutForwardRefWithAs {...props} ref={ref} />
));

Button.displayName = 'Button';

export { Button };
```

Working:

```
export const Button = forwardRefWithAs<NonSemanticButtonProps, 'button'>((props: ButtonProps, ref) => (
  <ButtonWithoutForwardRefWithAs {...props} ref={ref} />
));

Button.displayName = 'Button';
```